# JXDatePicker:unpearsable date

Tags: java, mysql, swing, date

I'm developing a small application with java swing and I'm stuck with the `JXDatePicker`
I need to convert the date from the datepicker so I can insert it in mysql DB
here is the code

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

Date invoiceDate = formatDate.parse(jXDatePicker3.getDate().toString());
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(Long.parseLong(dateFormat.format(invoiceDate)));
```

and this is the error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Dec 19 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2013"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the fact that `dateFormat.format` will return a `String`...

You could be trying something more like..

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(
    formatDate.parse(
        dateFormat.format(invoiceDate)).getTime());
```

Instead, or may be even...

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(invoiceDate.getTime());
```

Comment: thank's for your help, i did like you said but i get another error
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date"

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `dateFormat`.  Once the date is parsed you can simply use `getTime()` to return the long value to be used in the constructor.

```
public class DateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

        Date invoiceDate = formatDate.parse("Thu Dec 19 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2013");
            //Once you have a date use .getTime() to get Long value.
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(invoiceDate.getTime());
    }
}
```